# How to get the number of used elements of an array of structures in C?

Tags: c, arrays, structure

Say I have:

```
struct a b[4];
//i filled some elements of b
```

I need to know the number of non-empty elements of `b`.
Since I'm not sure whether `b` has exactly 4 non-empty elements, is there any way to do this?

Comment: i meant, non-populated ith element sorry

Comment: "non-populated" doesn't mean anything either. When you create `b`, four `struct a` elements are created. You'll need something in the structs themselves to know whether or not they are "in use"/"populated" - that depends on the semantics of your code (and you'll need to initialize them somehow)

Comment: yes it does. the array is initialized, but not all are populated.

Answer (score 3):

there is no way to retrieve this information. you have to keep track of the number of elements you use by yourself.

typically, C developpers use another integer value alongside the array:

```
struct a b[4];
int      b_count;
```

increment the counter each time you fill an element in the array.

you can wrap all this into a structure, in order to keep the counter near the array. this allows you to return the array along with the counter from a function:

```
struct array {
    struct a values[4];
    int      count;
};
struct array b;
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two normal ways to do this.

The first is to have some sort of sentinel value which indicates that the array element isn't in use. For example, if you were storing quantities in an integer, you could use the value `-1` to indicate it wasn't in use.

As a more relevant example to your situation:

```
struct a {
    int inUse;
    // all other fields in structure
};
```

and set `inUse` within the array element to 1 or 0 depending on whether that array element is in use.

The second is to maintain *extra* information outside of the array to indicate which elements were in use. This could be a map if the usage information was sparse, or just a count if you could guarantee active elements would be contiguous at the start.

For a map, you could use:

```
struct a b[4];
int inUse[4];    // shows inUse indication for each element.
```

For a simpler count variation:

```
struct a b[4];
int inUseAtStart;   // 0 thru 4 shows how many elements are in use,
                    //   starting at b[0].
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such **empty** or **non-empty** distinction in C.
The very thing you describe as **empty** may refer to uninitialized variables.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to keep track of how many elements of the array you use when you populate it. Note that **you will have to(==must)** do  this because in c, there is no bound checking for arrays,so you have to keep track that you do not exceed the bounds of the array(You end up with an Undefined Behavior if you don't), while doing so you can easily keep track of how many elements you used.

Answer (score 0):

C won't create any overhead in it's arrays and therefore it won't store any additional information including element count. There's a decent c++ std::vector template for it in case you don't want to do it yourself (which can be annoying) and in case you are willing to use c++, just saying :)

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you can do is **mark the next item** after the last item you inserted. For example you used 2 elements then you can mark the third element with a specific data like `-1`.

Another way is that you can do is to **keep a variable** which has the count of the elements in the struct.